# Airflow scheduler running Paused DAG continuously

Tags: scheduler, airflow

**Airflow webserver**

DAG is Paused:
[image: DAG is Paused]

**Airflow Scheduler keeps running the DAG**

I have a fresh install of Airflow. All paused examples are working fine. A new sample DAG keeps running even when it is PAUSED on the web. PAUSING/unPAUSING works fine on default examples. 
Other problem is, it is scheduled every 6hours. Why should it keep trying to run the DAG?

**SWAT_Tutorial_01.py**

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

default_args = {'owner': 'airflow',
        'depends_on_past': False,
        'start_date': datetime(2018, 3, 16),
        'email': ['sample@scholastic.com'],
        'email_on_failure': False,
        'email_on_retry': False,
        'retries': 1,
        'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
        # 'catchup': False,
        # 'queue': 'bash_queue',
        # 'pool': 'backfill',
        # 'priority_weight': 10,
        # 'end_date': datetime(2016, 1, 1),
}

dag = DAG( 'SWAT.Tutorial_01', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval=timedelta(hours=6))

# t1, t2 and t3 are examples of tasks created by instantiating operators
t1 = BashOperator( task_id='print_date', bash_command='date', dag=dag)

t2 = BashOperator( task_id='sleep', bash_command='sleep 5', retries=3, dag=dag)
t3 = BashOperator( task_id='hello', bash_command='echo "Hello World"', retries=3, dag=dag)

t2.set_upstream(t1)
t3.set_upstream(t1)
```

**Scheduler Log (keeps repeating)**

```
    File Path                                         PID  Runtime    Last Runtime    Last Run
----------------------------------------------  -----  ---------  --------------  ----------
/home/airflow/airflow/dags/SWAT_Tutorial_01.py  16930  0.00s
================================================================================
[2018-03-17 23:41:45,352] {jobs.py:1404} INFO - Heartbeating the process manager
[2018-03-17 23:41:45,352] {jobs.py:1440} INFO - Heartbeating the executor
[2018-03-17 23:41:46,354] {jobs.py:1404} INFO - Heartbeating the process manager
[2018-03-17 23:41:46,354] {dag_processing.py:559} INFO - Processor for /home/airflow/airflow/dags/SWAT_Tutorial_01.py finished
[2018-03-17 23:41:46,356] {dag_processing.py:627} INFO - Started a process (PID: 16932) to generate tasks for /home/airflow/airflow/dags/SWAT_Tutorial_01.py - logging into /var/log/airflow/scheduler/2018-03-17/SWAT_Tutorial_01.py.log
[2018-03-17 23:41:46,357] {jobs.py:1440} INFO - Heartbeating the executor
[2018-03-17 23:41:47,358] {jobs.py:1404} INFO - Heartbeating the process manager
[2018-03-17 23:41:47,359] {jobs.py:1440} INFO - Heartbeating the executor
[2018-03-17 23:41:48,360] {jobs.py:1404} INFO - Heartbeating the process manager
[2018-03-17 23:41:48,360] {dag_processing.py:559} INFO - Processor for /home/airflow/airflow/dags/SWAT_Tutorial_01.py finished
[2018-03-17 23:41:48,362] {dag_processing.py:627} INFO - Started a process (PID: 16934) to generate tasks for /home/airflow/airflow/dags/SWAT_Tutorial_01.py - logging into /var/log/airflow/scheduler/2018-03-17/SWAT_Tutorial_01.py.log
[2018-03-17 23:41:48,363] {jobs.py:1440} INFO - Heartbeating the executor
```

Comment: `Other problem is, it is scheduled every 6hours`. What is the problem here? Also, please [edit] your question and add details in how often the DAG runs even if you want it paused.

Comment: I also see this issue and I do have catch_up=False - so can't figure out why Airflow is busily consuming CPU cycles for paused DAGs either.

Comment: I'm having this issue as well (I have the DAG paused and it runs every second!) and I've tried all the mentioned recommendations (I even put the schedule interval as none, and put the start date in the future!)

Answer (score 0):

Just some random guess here.
I think airflow will not stop backfilling data even if you pause the dag, those jobs are probably backfilling jobs.
From your code it seems that you did not disable backfill(`catch_up = False`)